# Printing number of elements in a string but with some exception

Tags: python, arrays, string, element

so I wanted to count the number of elements in a string. However, there are some exceptions on how to solve this such as the use of len, count, max, min, string function, etc.

Say I have a string of 'hello' means that I wanted to make a program that gives the output which states the number of elements of the 'hello' string which there are 5 elements (index starts from 0 but counting from 1). One of the code that I've tried is that I've tried the looping method

```
i = 0
s = str(input("enter string : "))
while s[i] == s[i]:
print(i)
    i +=1
numb_elements = i + 1
print(numb_elements)
```

However, obviously, it'll show error since index = 5 is invalid for 'hello'. It's been only few days since I got my hand on python so I can't really think of a way

Comment: Why are there exceptions/restriction? Is this a homework exercise?

This can be done with the `len()` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

Comment: Be careful about the exception of  **indented block** (line that contains **i +=1**)

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to loop over the characters in a string to determine the length of the string without using `len()`? One possible way to do that would be:

```
strg = "hello"
count = 0
while True:
    try:
        strg[count]
    except IndexError:
        break
    else:
        count += 1
print(count)
```